# how can you use threading in python, so that it would change the value of i in loop which is outside class in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, function, python-multithreading

i am very new to coding ,,i started learning threading in python ,,, i achived it but now i want to do a bit diffirent thing but not getting the logic.please help me

```
from threading import *
import time
def thread1():
     for i in range (10):
          time.sleep(.2)
          print("hello")
          
class Hello(Thread):
     def run(self):
          thread1()
          
class Hi(Thread):
     def run(self):
          thread1()
          
t1=Hello()
t2=Hi()
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

here's the code, so what the code is doing is its printing hello 10 times on 1 thread each,
so 20 hello in total but i want it to print only 10 hello,, the threads need to start . lets consider each hello is numbered,so t1 needs to print hello1,hello3,hello5,hello7,hello9. and t2 needs to print hello2,hello4,hello6,hello8,hello10,. thank u

Comment: Both classes are running the same thread function `thread1()`, so you're getting 20 `hello`s; it's working like you programmed it.

Comment: Given your followup comments, you should use a `ThreadPool`

Comment: Use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor( https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: i know sir its working like how i programmed it ,,,thats why i posted the question here so i could find a way to programme it the way i want it ,,@barny